# Files in a certain folder only to be downloadable link on the site

Tags: .htaccess, search-engine

I need to protect some files in a folder (and its sub-folders, if possible) from:

• being indexed and shown by search engines

• being downloaded/opened by direct URLs or external links

I only want them to be downloadable/viewable via links placed on the site. What's the best way to do this? Note: no password protection please.

Many thanks!

Comment: http://domain.com/folder/filename.pdf – where domain.com is the own website address. So linking to that file should only be possible via link placed on the own site, and excluded from search engines.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent your pdf files directory from getting indexed by the search engines, create a plain text file named ***robots.txt*** at your website's root directory as

```
User-agent: * Disallow: /path/to/pdfs/folder/
```

You could also prevent indexing of all the pdfs anywhere on your website with

```
User-agent: * Disallow: /*.pdf$
```

Now to prevent downloading of your files through external links, just add the following to your .htaccess file located at the `/` root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf|doc|jpe?g)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?myownsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The above rules prevent accessing any pdf, doc and jpg files directly and show a 403 Forbidden error page instead. If you would like to redirect the users to your home page, just change the last rule to

```
RewriteRule ^ http://myownsite/ [R,L]
```